# GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.setTimes() not working

Tags: google-hadoop

I have a reference to the `GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase` in my java code, and I’m trying to call `setTimes(Path p, long mtime, long atime)` to modify the timestamp of a file.  It doesn’t seem to be working though, even though other FileSystem apis work fine.  From the console UI, I can only see the "last uploaded" time. Does the google file system only store the upload time, and thus ignore changes to the modification time and access time? I also checked the timestamp using `hadoop fs -ls gs://mybucket/`, but that timestamp also shows up as unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a limitation of [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) (GCS) and the [GCS Hadoop connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector). Specifically, [GCS objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) do not have `mtime` and `atime` which causes the underlying failure. As a workaround right now, HDFS attached to clusters should function normally.

Comment: Is this still true? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource does show a field called `updated` of type datetime, which seems to contradict the statement that GCS objects don't have an `mtime`.

Comment: This is still true because `updated` is a read only GCS attribute, that's why it can not be used to implement `FileSystem.setTimes(...)` method.